# Focus behaviour to 'follows-mouse' resets to 'onclick' on reboot (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, mouse, focus

Whenever I set the focus mode to 'follow mouse' with unity-tweak-tool, ubuntu-tweak or equal, this setting get's reset to 'on-click' whenever I reboot.

How can I make this setting permanent?

Comment: See some of the answers here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/64605/how-do-i-set-focus-follows-mouse .  I've used CCSM for settings (probably not ideal).  But try some of the command line suggestions there, etc. and let us know if anything works (or if all fail).