# Window settings in panel?

Tags: unity, mouse, unity-dash

I recently had to do a full reinstall of Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and lost all my files and settings.

I really like having the focus move with mouse or sloppy settings, but when I opened Unity Tweak Tool and set it to that, I realized that I couldn't access the window settings. (usually in the menu bar on the top of each window) it was in the launcher, and I can't find the setting to move it anywhere!

I know I was able to do it before, and I don't want to give up my auto-focusing mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set focus follows mouse?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64605/how-do-i-set-focus-follows-mouse)

Comment: no, I know how to do that. what I want is the menu on the panel to be on the titlebar. I know it can be done, as it used to be that way before my reset.

Comment: @ElderGeek it's not a duplicate. to the OP, please add a screenshot of the menu settings after you changed it

Comment: @Anwar Ok, in that case, [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/901557/225694) and CV retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For focus follows mouse and "sloppy":**

See the answers [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64605/how-do-i-set-focus-follows-mouse)

**For the menu bar:**

Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd><kbd>Appearance</kbd><kbd>Behavior</kbd> and adjust in the section circled below:

[image: titlebar]

Comment: Good that you answered. Now I'm thinking it might have been asked already ;)