# Cannot rename files or folders in Nautilus (long time running occuring issue)

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, rename, focus

When I run Ubuntu 16.04 for a long time (let us say minimum overnight, sitting idle) on my [ASUS ROG G752VSK](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/G752VL/0409_E10716_G752VL_VT_VY_C.pdf) laptop, Nautilus repeatedly run into this funny issue, which is described perfectly here:

[Cannot rename files or folders in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906945/cannot-rename-files-or-folders-in-nautilus)

With every reboot, which I try to avoid to let my work steady going on, it works all fine again.

So the main issue is that Nautilus is losing its focus and so in the end I cannot rename files here. For example. Of course all provided solutions in the link are not working, but there is no solution voted up or marked as solved.

Use of my system:

1. The only really extensive use is Google Chrome Browser (many tabs
   and windows), which by the way causes sometimes the "frozen" windows
   effect, which only affects the actual windows of chrome. Here I can
   help myself closing the window and reopen it (restore option of the
   tabs)
2. Several remote connections to my raspberry pi and my Synology NAS
   via terminal and ssh.
3. Some open Editors like [notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/s/) or [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) show similar behaviour

My only question is:
Did someone suffices the same behaviour and perhaps knows a root cause for this? As told, it happens only after a really long time of idling, like overnight or so...

[EDIT] Of course I do have a swap partition - it should match my 24 GB RAM, but here is the output of `sudo swapon --show`:

```
NAME      TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-0 partition 22,9G  88M   -2
```

Comment: 16.04 predates the kernel which solved slow swap files, so do you have a swap partition? Please check its size with gparted, and if there is none, then check for a swap file with `sudo swapon --show` then come back here, click [edit] and tell us if you have a swap partition or swap file.

Comment: @K7AAY I provided the info you need. I am pretty sure that it should match the size of the RAM but maybe the partitioning tool also takes 1000 MB = 1GB? But anyway, the usage is very low, why the reported misbehaviour of nautilus is active at the moment!

Comment: TY for the accurate and useful response which eliminates the only cause I could think of. Topic Draft: https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/ suggests you might dial back the swap space to at least equal to the square root of the RAM size and at most double the size of RAM UNLESS you use Hibernation (then you have exactly what you need), or resource heavy applications like video editors are used.

Comment: Thanks @k7aay! Square that means something incredibly big like 24x24 GB? Or at least 48 GB? I have a hibernation Mode activated. I think i guess it should be active... Why is this and how can i prove IT?

Comment: Since you hibernate, your swap space should equal your total RAM. For reference, _Square root_ was the term used for non-hibernating systems; the number which, if you square it, equals your desired value. You have 24 GiB RAM, or 24.576 GB. The square root is 24 GiB is 4.9 GiB, or 5.02 GB.